# Editing a sticky input element in Chrome causes the page to scroll to the top

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-position, sticky

I was trying to use the css `position: sticky` in one of my personal project when I noticed that having editable elements like input fields or text-areas inside, trigger the page to scroll to the top.

I would really like to remove this behaviour if possible.

```css
.container {
  height: 5000px;
}

.heading{
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <input placeholder="Edit this while scrolling...">
  </div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>  
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `sticky` is still experimental. There's a good chance that this is simply an unaddressed bug and your best bet (as much as I'd like to see a solution to this) is probably to implement your own sticky-like behaviour.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behavior on? It does not occur in Firefox.

Comment: It happens in Chrome

Comment: Vertically centering the input field (or scrolling to top in this scenario as there is not enough content above) when typing in an input field that is out of the viewing range is the default behaviour in Chrome for relative positioned inputs, so that I go with @George that this very likely is an edge case they haven't addressed.

Comment: You actually want to have this behaviour, but not in case the input element is visible due to it's currently sticky ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyrz7v0x/)).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do some validation of the key - probably best with a regex check to confirm acceptable characters, but you can call a javascript function from the keypress, update the value of the input, and return false:

```js
var e = document.getElementById('input');
e.onkeypress = myFunction;

function myFunction(t) {
  document.getElementById('input').value += t.key;
  return false;
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

.heading{
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <input id="input" placeholder="Edit this while scrolling...">
  </div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>  
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, that's a good way around. Not 100% what I was looking for but I can readapt to my own scenario.

Comment: position: -webkit-sticky doesn't exist. You're just adding unnecessary bytes to your CSS by having it.

Comment: it looks like it does here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#Sticky_positioning

Comment: Looks like it will still scroll when you press backspace

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make it work, but it's probably not the best solution.

1. Add add either `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` to the class with `position: sticky`.
2. Remove the `placeholder` from `<input>`.

I'm not sure why adding `overflow` or removing the `placeholder` makes it work, maybe someone can help explain this.

```css
.container {
  height: 5000px;
}

.heading{
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <input>
  </div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>  
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately that way-around doesn't work my Angular2+ project using Angular Material. The issue remain visible whether I remove the placeholder and I change the element's overflow

Comment: any news about that? Is there any reported bug?

Comment: @user2010955 yea the bug is reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334207
And fixed but still visible in chrome when enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Answer (score 1):

For the next person wasting there time like me, This bug has been reported to chrome and has been fixed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334207

but, it is still visible in chrome when enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag is enabled